# Authentication with JWT Lumen without password

Tags: jwt, lumen

I am using JWT in lumen and am unable to get token without password only With Email and  i am using this code form [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028630/authentication-with-jwt-laravel-5-without-password) --

```
 $user=User::where('email','=','user2@gmail.com')->first();

if (!$userToken=JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }

return response()->json(compact('userToken'));



 This code give me error like this ->

 ErrorException in UserController.php line 44:
Non-static method Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

My controller UserController.php -

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\v1;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Exception;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Model\User;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
```

My - Config/auth

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */
    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver'     => 'jwt',
            'provider'   => 'users',
            'identifier' => 'email',
            'password'   => 'password',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => \App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        //
    ],

];
```

My bootstrap/app

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . '/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Create The Application
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
  | that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
  | application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
  |
 */

$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
        realpath(__DIR__ . '/../')
);

$app->withFacades();

$app->configure('jwt');
$app->configure('auth');

class_alias(Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class, 'JWTAuth');
class_alias(Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class, 'JWTFactory');

$app->withEloquent();

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Register Container Bindings
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
  | register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
  | your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
  |
 */

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::class
);


/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Register Middleware
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
  | be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
  | route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
  |
 */
// $app->middleware([
//    App\Http\Middleware\ExampleMiddleware::class
// ]);

$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth'        => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'jwt.auth'    => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
]);

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Register Service Providers
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
  | are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
  | totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
  |
 */

$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Load The Application Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
  | the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
  | can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
  |
 */

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

return $app;
```

My Model User -

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Model implements JWTSubject, AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract {

    use Authenticatable,
        Authorizable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }

}
```

My - JwtSubject -

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of jwt-auth.
 *
 * (c) Sean Tymon <tymon148@gmail.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts;

interface JWTSubject
{
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier();

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims();
}
```

My  function __construct

class UserController extends Controller {

```
public $request;
protected $jwt;

public function __construct(Request $request, JWTAuth $jwt) {
    try {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        \Log::error("Error : " . $ex);
        $output = array('success' => false, 'result' => null, 'error' => $ex, 'error_key' => 'unhandled_exception');
        return new Response($output);
    }
}
```

Please help me how can i get token using only Email.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by this `use` statement in your UsersController.

```php
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;
```

When you call `JWTAuth::fromUser($user)` you are not  referencing the Facade (that contains an instance of `JWTAuth` already) but the actual function of the class, which you can't because it's not called statically.

This is what builds the Facade:

```php
class_alias(Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class, 'JWTAuth');
```

Remove that `use` statement and you should be fine.

Or modify it to `use JWTAuth;` so that you're referencing properly the Facade that is globally accessible.

Comment: My function __construct

class UserController extends Controller {

public $request;
protected $jwt;

public function __construct(Request $request, JWTAuth $jwt) {
    try {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        \Log::error("Error : " . $ex);
        $output = array('success' => false, 'result' => null, 'error' => $ex, 'error_key' => 'unhandled_exception');
        return new Response($output);
    }
}

Comment: Sir thank for your replay but now i am getting other error - Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of App\Model\User given, called in C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php on line 217 and defined
Please help me about this error